# Getting the most square divisors from a number

Tags: java

I trying to find the most square divisors of a number. For instance, if my number is `15` I need `3` and `5`. If the number is `18` I'd need `3` and `6`.

I've almost done what I need, but I cant figure out the last step, which is probably the easiest...

Here is my code:

```
    int divisor;
    int divisor1 = 0;
    int num = gridArr.length;

    for(divisor = (int)Math.sqrt(num); divisor>0; divisor--){
        if(num%divisor==0){
            divisor1 = num/divisor;       
        }
    }
    System.out.println(divisor+" "+divisor1);
```

In this case the output is:

```
0 15
```

If I move the `System.out.print` inside of the if statement the output is:

```
3 5
1 15
```

and I only need `3 5`.

I don't know where I am going wrong... Any ideas?

Comment: What does "square divisor" mean? How is 3 a square divisor of 15?

Comment: `break` out of your for loop inside the if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I don't know what "most square divisor" is exactly, but I'll assume that it means that you want to factor the number into two factors that are as close to equal as possible. You only need a minor revision of your code: once you find one factor pair, simply stop looking for any others. To do that, just break out of the loop:

```
for(divisor = (int)Math.sqrt(num); divisor>0; divisor--){
    if(num%divisor==0){
        divisor1 = num/divisor;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup! That was it. Thanks.